# django-tastypie ToOneField

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I can't seem to figure out how to get ToOneField to work in django-tastypie.

```
>> pip freeze | grep django-tastypie
django-tastypie==0.10.0
```

Here's my model and resources (sample_territory is always null with the following code):

## Model

```
class Sample(ProjectModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    territory = models.OneToOneField(Territory, null=True, related_name='sample_territory')
```

## TerritoryResource

```
class TerritoryResource(ProjectResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Territory.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'sample_territory'
```

## SampleResource

```
class SampleResource(ProjectResource):

    sample_territory = fields.ToOneField(TerritoryResource, 'sample_territory', related_name='sample_territory', null=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Sample.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I didn't understand tastypie's attribute field option well enough.

https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html?highlight=toonefield#attribute

In my case the solution was:

```
sample_territory = fields.ToOneField(TerritoryResource, attribute='territory', null=True, full=True)
```